# How to fetch data on server-side from external API within ReactJS-based node application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I try hard to fetch data from external API within a React-App. But it always gives me the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://api.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is my code:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const URL = 'http://api.example.com/my/api/request' // obfuscated

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL).then( response => {
      console.log(response);
    })  
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <small>You are running this application in <b>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</b> mode.</small>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React!</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As far as i know the CORS-thing is only required on client-side requests, not for server-side requests.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` hook will never be called on the server side. As a result, your fetch code is only running in the browser after an application has been mounted into your DOM. To fetch data from the server you can use fetch inside `componentWillMount` hook, it will be called on the server, but on the client too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call api request on the server, wait for the response and return rendered html page.

I have created a starter for server-side rendering https://github.com/gzoreslav/react-redux-saga-universal-application

It uses redux and redux-saga